why boost asio tcp resolver creates threads for async resolve
When I use the following code, it spawns a new thread.
resolver_.async_resolve(
      host_, port_,
      beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_resolve, shared_from_this()));

But when I change it with non-async version, it does not create a new thread.
  boost::system::error_code err;
  auto const& results = resolver_.resolve(host_, port_, err);
  on_resolve(err, results);

Resolver definition:
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver_;

This behaviour is not documented anywhere and I have been trying to understand for a hour where this thread is spawned because it basically empty thread and does not destructed anytime. Here is the screenshot of the thread details.

Boost version: boost/1.82.0
What is the purpose of this thread, and how is it related to the boost tcp async resolve?

resolver_.async_resolve(...  - "Asynchronously perform forward resolution of a query" so the call will create a thread to perform the query and return immediately before the query is complete.   Creating threads is expensive so the resolver is probably keeping the thread for any subsequent queries.  Basically "async" anything either needs it's own thread or use of a thread pool.

@RichardCritten I see. How to kill or handle that newly created thread? Can we somehow get native handler?

ip::basic_resolver::cancel to cancel any pending calls. Or ip::basic_resolver::~basic_resolver should release all resources.  Killing threads will result in Undefined Behaviour as when a thread is killed the program will be left in an unknown state.

@RichardCritten I think the thread is pooled and owned by the service implementation. It might go away when you reset the context, but realistically it may be retained until destruction of the execution context. After all, it's a platform dependent implementation detail (see my answer)

The creation of the thread is very exactly governed by the corresponding service implementation in the execution context. This is an implementation detail, that you should not worry about.
It is documented here under "Platform Specific Implementation Notes":

An additional thread per io_context is used to emulate asynchronous host resolution. This thread is created on the first call to either ip::tcp::resolver::async_resolve() or ip::udp::resolver::async_resolve().

